# Authenticate phpBB using custom MS-SQL database

Tags: php, phpbb, sql

How can I let my users to log into a phpBB forum by entering their user credentials while these credentials are stored in a separate MS SQL database?

I mean I need to customize the authentication routine so it looks into MS SQL database for user credentials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to integrate phpBB with an existing database, the easiest way to do it would probably be to replicate the user table in the phpBB database. Otherwise, you could try [this auth plugin](http://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?t=1598865).